# unchecked call to ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, warnings, compiler-warnings

I get the following warning when I instantiate my ArrayAdapter (compiles fine):

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,java.util.List<T>) as a member of the raw type android.widget.ArrayAdapter
      ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(CFAMain.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
```

And here's the problem line:

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(CFAMain.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why it's giving me this warning?

Comment: And yes, I did look this up in Google, and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

That's because `ArrayAdapter` expects you to specify which type of object it will manipulate. So, in order to avoid those warnings just do:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CFAMain.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
```

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out a few seconds before you posted this - thanks though :)

Comment: I put <String> but it shows: Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(xxxxxx) .

Comment: @Raymond try 
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(CFAMain.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);