# LogCat errors stopping application from running - Code added

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Having trouble with my application when attempting to use the class below, see LogCat and .Java class. Anyone able to explain and diagnose this?

AddActivity.java

```
02-16 14:17:52.046    1896-1896/com.example.student.neillapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.student.neillapp, PID: 1896
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.student.neillapp/com.example.student.neillapp.AddActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.student.neillapp.AddActivity.chooseCategory(AddActivity.java:39)
            at com.example.student.neillapp.AddActivity.onCreate(AddActivity.java:26)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

This is the java file associated with the CatLog

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner02);

    chooseCategory();
    chooseBreakfast();
    chooseLunch();
    chooseDinner();
    chooseSnack();

}
static Spinner spinner1, spinner2 = null;

public void chooseCategory() {

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.foodtype, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    catAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(catAdapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new planOnSelectedListener());
}

public void chooseBreakfast() {

    ArrayAdapter<Food> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Food[]{
            new Food(1, "Toast"),
            new Food(99, "Cereal"),
            new Food(53, "Fruit"),
            new Food(153, "Yogurt")
    });

    spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter1);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button01);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void chooseLunch() {
    ArrayAdapter<Food> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Food[]{
            new Food(1, "Sandwich"),
            new Food(99, "Wrap"),
            new Food(53, "Salad"),
    });

    spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);
    // Tell the spinner what to do when an item is changed
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    // Find our button and hook-up the click routine
    Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button01);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void chooseDinner() {
    ArrayAdapter<Food> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Food[]{
            new Food(1, "Pizza"),
            new Food(99, "Pasta"),
            new Food(53, "Fish and Chips"),
    });

    spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);
    // Tell the spinner what to do when an item is changed
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    // Find our button and hook-up the click routine
    Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button01);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void chooseSnack() {
    ArrayAdapter<Food> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Food[]{
            new Food(1, "Crisps"),
            new Food(99, "Chocolate"),
            new Food(53, "Donut"),
    });

    spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);
    // Tell the spinner what to do when an item is changed
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    // Find our button and hook-up the click routine
    Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button01);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void toastState(String prefix, Food cl) {
    if (cl != null) {
        String desc = "Event: " + prefix + "\nName: " + cl.name;
        desc += "\nCalorie: " + String.valueOf(cl.calories);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), desc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void calorieState (Food cl){

        TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView3.setText(String.valueOf("Item Calories: " + cl.getCalorie()));

}

public class planOnSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

        if (pos == 0) {
            chooseBreakfast();
        } else if (pos == 1) {
            chooseLunch();
        } else if (pos == 2) {
            chooseDinner();
        } else if (pos == 3) {
            chooseSnack();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
    Food st = (Food) spinner2.getSelectedItem();

    // Show it via a toast
    toastState("onItemSelected", st);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}


public void onClick(View v){
    // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
    Food st = (Food) spinner2.getSelectedItem();

    // Show it via a toast
    toastState("onClick", st);
    calorieState(st);
```

Comment: Are you sure `spinner01` and `spinner01` Spinner is in `activity_main`  layout?

Comment: your right i switched my activities, adding a home activity, so i should have changed activity_main to activity_add, and never changed it... so silly! thanks, blinded by staring at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Should be

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
```