# create adapter to fill Spinner with objects

Tags: android, object, spinner, adapter

I have an Android application with a `Spinner` and want to fill it dynamically with my own objects. The objects do exist already as a `List<T>`.

The objects are of type `Category`:

```
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // constructors
    // getter & setter
    // hashCode, equals
    // toString
}
```

I know that I have to write a Adapter. How do I do that? I've tried to find some examples... no luck. Please advice.

Comment: Check out the following answer for a full solution on how to do this without creating a *CustomAdapter*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21169383/293280

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is my 5 cents. I had a similar problem. I was working with SimpleCursorAdapter which implements interface SpinnerAdapter, but arrived only until SDK version 11 (Android 3.0). I intended my app to work with SDK 8 (Android 2.2) and up, so I had to replace SimpleCursorAdapter with another, or my own. The real challenger was that I also used a custom XML layout for spinner and in it showed several fields from cursor i.e. cursor adapter. So here is my solution after a lot of research, and the info wasn't easy to come by.

Here is the layout file used in spinner named spin_layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/field1"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/field2"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the adapter implementing SpinnerAdapter and extending (using as a little helper) BaseAdapter. The Cursor that was used originally was transformed into List and passed in constructor, together with activity containing the spinner.

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter{
    private Activity activity;
    private List<BusLines> list_bsl; 

    public MyCursorAdapter(Activity activity, List<BusLines> list_bsl){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list_bsl = list_bsl;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list_bsl.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list_bsl.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return list_bsl.get(position).getId();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View spinView;
    if( convertView == null ){
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        spinView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spin_layout, null);
    } else {
         spinView = convertView;
    }
    TextView t1 = (TextView) spinView.findViewById(R.id.field1);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) spinView.findViewById(R.id.field2);
    t1.setText(String.valueOf(list_bsl.get(position).getLine_Num()));
    t2.setText(list_bsl.get(position).getName());
    return spinView;
    }
}
```

Unlike other solutions you find on the web, method **getItemId** establishes link with **id** field from database, just like SimpleCursorAdapter. That id is the argument passed in **onItemSelected**(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position, long **id**) in OnItemSelectedListener for **spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener**. Method **getView** inflated **spin_layout.xml**, identifies the two views contained in layout and assigns them values (as String!).

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter is on the android.support.v4 package, so with that you can use it clear back to API 4.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [simple example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/). Don't be fooled by the "cursor" name, it's just using a List. The idea is simple: extend from `BaseAdapter` and implement any missing methods (it's an abstract class); and don't forget to override the `getView()` method to provide the "visual" representation of your `Category`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this helps, but the Android SDK has a nice little example of supplying data to a Spinner from an array.  Converting a List to an array is trivial, so maybe this will point you in the right direction.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Spinner/src/com/android/example/spinner/SpinnerActivity.html

Good luck.

Comment: The example fills spinner from an array from layout, not dynamically created. Such answers are for nothing!