# How to use spinner in Android in this particular way?

Tags: java, android, spinner, adapter

So, I have an ArrayList that has name and id

```
Gil 232
Asty 2423 and so on.
```

To use it in the spinner, what I did was to create two separate String Arraylists. One containing the names and the other the corresponding ids. So, that once the user is selected, I will get the corresponding id from the position.

I am not sure how to do that last part. As to, how to get the position?> `parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();`
This gives me the name again and not the position of the name in the ArrayList which I can use to retrieve the ID from the other list. How to do it? And, is their a better way to go about it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625249/android-how-to-bind-spinner-to-custom-object-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

---

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> implements Spinner
                                                      .OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        parent, false);
        Data data = getItem(position);
        // Do something with data and view here
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                                                int position, long arg4) {
        Data data = getItem(position);
        // Do something with data here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }

}
```

Then create an `ArrayList<Data>` and use with your `CustomAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

The `pos` variable is the position of item selected from Spinner, so you can use this position to get the id (from second ArrayList) of corresponding name which is selected.

As a alternative you can also create a `HashMap<String,String> map`
 and in that map put values like `map.put(name,id);` so when user will select value from Spinner you will have the name selected.And then use the map to get corresponding id

```
like String id = map.get(selected_name);
```

Hope it will help.