# Error: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

Tags: android

I have list that retrive a form my sql with (`course id- course name`).

I use a hash her for the list, I create an adapter which give me the list and I set it to spinner. 
However there is a problem  in log cat that said:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, T[]), you will find that the array adapter is expecting that the second parameter is a resource id of a text view **not a layout**..

initialize your adapter using:

```
new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, coursesList);
```

Comment: text view of what i have only spinner  ?

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   
      <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/chooseCourse"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
 
her is my xml

Comment: do you know how can i change the layout so it display only the name and the id is hidden

Comment: if you pass a list containing only the names..http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1517

Comment: but i want to have the id ? cause it is really important

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625249/android-how-to-bind-spinner-to-custom-object-list

Answer (score 4):

as Very well Explain by Luksprog :

The ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView XML exception means you don't supply what the ArrayAdapter expects. When you use this constructor:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, this.file)
```

**R.Layout.a_layout_file** must be an xml layout **where the first element must be a TextView**, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    //other attributes 
/>
```

If you want your list row layout to be something a little different then a simple TextView element use this constructor:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, 
   R.id.the_id_of_a_textview_from_the_layout, this.file)
```

where you supply the **id** of a layout that can contain various views, but also must contain a TextView with and id(third parameter) that you pass to your ArrayAdapter so it can know where to put the Strings

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   
      <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/chooseCourse"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
 
her is my xml what should i do