# SQLite Foreign Key Display

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to build a simple project with the following tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE artist(
 artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
 artistname  TEXT
 );
 CREATE TABLE track(
 trackid     INTEGER,
 trackname   TEXT, 
 trackartist INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
 );
```

I want my app to be user-friendly so how may I display the artistname instead of the artistid in the spinner of My Track Form? What SQLite statement should I use? After displaying all the artist names, what SQLite statement should I use to insert properly in my database?

Track Form Example:

Track Name: [EditText]

Artist: [Spinners]

Comment: Don't you want to display *all* artist names in the spinner's list?

Comment: Yes, I want to display all of them.

Comment: @Simulant You'd still need the ID.

Comment: Hello guys, I updated my question. I want to hear your ideas on how to implement the insert statement after displaying the artist names.

Comment: That INSERT statement is simple. What specific problem do you have with it?

Comment: For example, the value displayed of the spinner is "Linkin Park" so this is obviously a string by the trackartist column datatype is integer. How do I retrieve the artistid?

Comment: Your problem is not with the SQL; it is about how to manage the data inside your app. (Look at [Joaquin Alberto's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8116756/11654).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Statement returns a List of Artist names and their track-names.

```
SELECT a.artistname, t.trackname
FROM artistname a, track t
WHERE a.artistid = t.trackartist;
```