# How to insert object in a spinner

Tags: android, object, spinner

I want to know how I can put a spinner in an activity filled with values of an object.

I used to do spinners with:

```
sp_usage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

The case is that I receive an array of object from a server with items with ID and NAME. I want to know how I can know what item is selected, so I need to resend the ID to the server.

NOTE: The IDs received haven't to be sequences, they could be 1,23,47...

I uses this object:

```
public class Usages {

    @Key
    public String idd;

    @Key
    public String msgerror;

    @Key
    public String usage;

    public String getIdd() {
        return idd;
    }

    public void setIdd(String idd) {
        this.idd = idd;
    }

    public String getMsgerror() {
        return msgerror;
    }

    public void setMsgerror(String msgerror) {
        this.msgerror = msgerror;
    }

    public String getUsages() {
        return usage;
    }

    public void setUsages(String usages) {
        this.usage = usage;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usages{" +
                "idd='" + idd + '\'' +
                ", msgerror='" + msgerror + '\'' +
                ", usage='" + usage + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: which value u want to display in spinner?? id or name

Comment: Chandru, I want to display NAME but I need to send the ID. I'm trying to adapt this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625249/android-how-to-bind-spinner-to-custom-object-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8116756/4195406 you might be looking for this answer?

Comment: Thanks, it is better answer than the other post.