# bind a spinner in android using Sugar ORM

Tags: android, spinner, sugarorm

I am using Sugar Orm, and i want to bind a spinner, code

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

Spinner spnAge;
ArrayAdapter<Age> ageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    new LoadAsync().execute("");
}

private class LoadAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
return  "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        spnAge = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnAge);
        List<Age> ages = Age.listAll(Age.class);


        ageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Age>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ages);

        ageAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spnAge.setAdapter(ageAdapter);
    }
}
}
```

but code doesn't work and display a log:

> Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126690/603270

Comment: thanks, i did it, but again doesn't work.

Comment: What means "It does not work exactly?"

Comment: hi, i missed something, thanks a lot

Comment: What did you missed? Did it worked? If so, post your answer.

Comment: after closing and re opening AVD Sugar orm create a new database, and my data were lost, i didn't know it. my problem was here.

Comment: Answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625249/android-how-to-bind-spinner-to-custom-object-list