# getView Custom Spinner Android not Called?

Tags: java, android

I want to create custom spinner and this is CustomSpinnerAdapter  :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (data == null) ? 0 : data.size();
}
@Override
public long getItemId (int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_ip, parent, false);
    TextView ip = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ip);
    ip.setText(data.get(position).toString());
    return row;
}
```

and implement in Fragment

```
List<String> dataIpList = new ArrayList<String>();
dataIpList.add("192.168.1.1");
        dataIpList.add("192.168.1.2");
        dataIpList.add("192.168.1.3");
        dataIpList.add("192.168.1.4");

        _spinnerIpAdapter = new spinnerIpAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item_ip, dataIpList);
        publicIP.setAdapter(_spinnerIpAdapter);
```

the result is getDropDownView us called , but getView never called .

so how to fix it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625249/android-how-to-bind-spinner-to-custom-object-list  follow above link