# How to separate label and value in Spinners?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a spinner that shows data from an API that returns `Pasta` objects.

I want the Spinner's selectable label to be `Pasta.label`, but I want the actual value returned from the Spinner to be another value (`Pasta.Id`).
Kind of like this in HTML:

```html
<select>
    <option value="spag">Spaghetti</option>
    <option value="ravi">Ravioli</option>
</select>
```

I've seen other questions on SO but none of them seem truly conclusive.

I already have the `HashMap<String, String>` with the values I need. I just need to figure out how to translate that into a spinner. I thought about just creating a Class like this:

```
public class SpinnerItem {
    public String key;
    public String value;
}
```

and populating my Spinner with SpinnerItems, so that when I retrieve the SpinnerItem later on I can just do `getSelectedItem().getKey()`, but how would I go about writing an ArrayAdapter that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need toString function in your SpinnerItem class

```
public class SpinnerItem {
    public String key;
    public String value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

There is a readily available sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21169383/928492) as well, hope it helps.