# How can I convert an array into an Android resource?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'm new to Android programming, so please let me know if I'm doing anything stupid. However, I currently have an array `String[] gamesList` that is dynamically generated from a database.

I want to use each element of an array in a Spinner, but the Adapter has a method signature of `(Context, int, int)`. The first and third inputs I can do, but the second is asking for the id of a resource; but I don't have a `R.array.someRandomName` resource, I only have a local array.

Is there some way to make the array a resource, or if not, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `ArrayAdapter` out of your array (read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)), then call the Spinner's  `setAdapter()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Making the array into a resource is an unnecessary and unconventional step. Instead, you should look at this previous question: 
[Android - configure Spinner to use array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587028/android-configure-spinner-to-use-array)

Answer (score 0):

If the list of strings is fixed, you can use a [String Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray). You can also use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) for dynamically generated arrays of strings.