# Using entryValues with Spinner element

Tags: android, android-spinner

I create a `Spinner` element inside of my `LinearLayout`. I want to make values different from visible. I don't want to do that programmatically. I want to use arrays that below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="select">
        <item>a</item>
        <item>b</item>
        <item>c</item>
    </string-array>

    <integer-array name="selectValues">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

Simply. If `a` selected item, I want to get `1` as integer. What's the way?

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sSelect"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:entries="@array/select"
        android:entryValues="@array/selectValues" />
```

When I use above with below.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> item, View arg1, int sort,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String selectedItem = item.getItemAtPosition(sort).toString();
}
```

I just can get data as string and not values. I can get values that visible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - configure Spinner to use array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587028/android-configure-spinner-to-use-array)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keep the selected values as a [`TypedArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html) and access those in [`onItemSelected()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method.

```
// Keep the selected values as TypedArray
Resources res = getResources();
final TypedArray selectedValues = res
        .obtainTypedArray(R.array.selectValues);

Spinner spinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSelect));
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        //Get the selected value
        int selectedValue = selectedValues.getInt(position, -1);
        Log.d("demo", "selectedValues = " + selectedValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you let me know about Resources and getResources function?

Comment: [`getResources()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) is a method you can access from any activity class.

Comment: Can you show the corresponding logcat data with your that part of code ?

Comment: I have posted here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043710/getting-unfortunately-has-stopped-error-when-using-resources