# getting "unfortunately has stopped" error when using resources

Tags: android

I think I don't need to tell what I try to but I want to tell. There is 2 `<string-array>` first is for `android:entries` second for values of these entries. When user selects the item I want to get value of that item.

**Also I want to ask, When application is opened, dialog run. I want to make it run just when after user select an item.**

```
public class Select extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    Resources rsc = getResources();
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    final TypedArray itemValues = rsc.obtainTypedArray(R.array.selectValues);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select);

        Spinner form = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSelect);
        form.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> item, View arg1, int sort,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int selectedItem = itemValues.getInt(sort, 1);
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t.setText(selectedItem);
        d.setContentView(t);
        d.setTitle("Sonuc!");
        d.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Problem appear when I use `Resources`. Also logcat is [here](http://pastebin.com/W2z1LV5a). What's the problem and solution of this problem?

EDIT:
Also here is the array.xml

```
<resources>

    <string-array name="select">
        <item>Strength</item>
        <item>Size</item>
        <item>Fat loss</item>
    </string-array>

    <integer-array name="selectValues">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

please call getResource in onCreate() method.

Comment: changed but nothing change.

Comment: the crash can be happen to create the dialog in you event processing thread.

Comment: initialize `res` & `itemValues` both in `onCreate()` after the line  `setContentView(R.layout.select);` . And use ` Log.d ( "demo " , selectedItem )` in the `onItemSelected()` method.