# Adding integer values to my array

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my breakfast spinner, with a selection of my possible breakfast meals in an array... how would i add the functionality to show the calories of the selected food by the user.

```
 private void chooseBreakfast() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    List<String> planlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    planlist.add("Cereal");
    planlist.add("Porrige");
    planlist.add("Fruit");
    ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist);
    planAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter1);
```

Comment: you can use `HashMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Food.java object:

```
class Food{
  String name;
  int calories;
  // getters and setters
  public String toString(){
     return name + " (" + calories + ")"; // return your description here
  }
}
```

And then you create a Food list:

```
List<Food> planlist = new ArrayList<Food>();
planlist.add(new Food("Cereal", 20));
planlist.add(new Food("Porrige", 25));
planlist.add(new Food("Fruit", 10));

ArrayAdapter<Food> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<Food>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist);
planAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter1);
```

Look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587028/android-configure-spinner-to-use-array).