# How to set value of custom spinner android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

So, I create custom spinner base on tutorial from ([Android - configure Spinner to use array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587028/android-configure-spinner-to-use-array)) and (http://www.katr.com/article_android_spinner01.php)
and her the exxample of my code

```
      getAkun.getAkunUserKategori(data,tipee, new Akun_Get.dataCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void getData(List<tblAkunDatabase> value) {
            result = value;
            List<spinerAkun> daatspiner;
            daatspiner = new ArrayList<spinerAkun>();
            for(int i = 0;i< result.size();i++)
            {
                daatspiner.add(new spinerAkun(result.get(i).getKdAkun(),result.get(i).getNmAkun()));

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Edit_Jurnal.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, daatspiner);
                spin.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }

    });
```

so, actualy it's working. But the problem is when I try to set a spinner value from database. by using `spin.setSelection(daatspiner.indexof("datafromdatabase"))` . But it get a error "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundExceptionn: String resource ID #0xffffffff at .....". So to fix that? Thank You

**update**

ok, I don't know if this's really solve my problem or not. But my win win solution is create a another array, so I can get the index from tatx array and use the index from taht array to my spinner `spin.setSelection(Arrays.asList(array).indexOf("value"))`

Comment: If I understand your question you want to add database values to the spinner, and then select one of the spinner values ?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira yes, after I get a pupulate data from database to spinner I want to set the selected value to spinner base on selected data on database

Comment: the `daatspiner.indexof("datafromdatabase")` is a number ?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira yes, try to get an index number of the value using "datafromdatabase"

Comment: And if you do this `Integer.parseInt(daatspiner.indexof("datafromdatabase"))` so code will be `spin.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(daatspiner.indexof("datafromdatabase")))`

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I try already try `spin.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(daatspiner.indexof("dataf‌​romdatabase")))` but I got error message "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff when try to get

Comment: probably inside you are adding a new adapter to the spinner every time the for executes, what happens if you execute this `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Edit_Jurnal.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, daatspiner);
                spin.setAdapter(adapter);
` outside the for loop

Comment: @BrunoFerreira can you explain me more spesificly?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira if I try to show daatspiner.indexof("datafromdatabase") in log, it return -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My win win solution is create a another array, so I can get the index from tatx array and use the index from taht array to my spinner `spin.setSelection(Arrays.asList(array).indexOf("value"))`